# Port 443 unavailable on IIS

Tags: windows, tomcat, iis, server, port

I have a strange problem on Windows server hosting IIS and Apache Tomcat. I have few available ports enabled from network administrators and 443 is one of them. Also I have few web apps running on IIS and Apache Tomcat on the same server. I also have the appropriate certificate.
When i use some other ports for the apps everything works fine. But when i switch one of the apps to work on 443 regardless if it is on IIS or Apache i have strange situation where i can access it from inside it's local network bout by IP or DNS but when i try to access it from outside (Internet) the tab on the browser is circling like it is connecting but the connection never happens. So no timeout no Not Accessible or anything like that, it just stays as it is connecting the whole time.

I like to mention that when i test the port from outside with
'tnc domain.com -p 443'
it says that the port is open.

Also i have a development server with the same configuration (as i am told) and there the port is working.

Does anyone knows what can be the problem and maybe more important how can i diagnose this. I used netsat and i can see that the port is open and listening, but i have no idea if anything is coming to that server or the request stops somewhere.

The firewall is disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: So again, let your network administrators work on it. That’s more likely to be a network configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue more relates to your outside network environment instead of the local IIS web server if it works properly inside your local network. Please check your outside gateway, which controls on your public DNS, such as the Network Security Group protecting Azure Virtual Machine.
https://build5nines.com/securing-azure-virtual-machines-using-network-security-groups-nsgs/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I will do that next. Since i end up doing the deployment besides development without knowing the infrastructure or even access to it i needed outside opinion on this :)